# Does glDisplayFunc(RenderScene) callback causes a race condition in the following code?

Tags: c, opengl, race-condition

I'm reading [OpenGL Superbible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321498828) 4th ed.  In Chapter 2, the example code sets up the callback followed by the clear color as follows:

```
main()
{
//...
glDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
SetupRC();
//..
}    

void RenderScene(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glFlush();
}

void SetupRC(void)
{
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Is it posisble that we have a race condition here, where `glClear` might be executed before `glClearColor`?

Comment: It cannot be a race condition. It must be in the same thread (thus sequential), as OpenGL contexts _cannot_ be shared between threads.

Comment: Also, because the question title sounded like it asked this, you *can* call glClear before glClearColor; the specification defines the original clear color to be all zeros.

Comment: @IanMallett - Thanks, yes that was part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a race condition, because `glutMainLoop()` runs in the same thread and calling the `glDisplayFunc()` does not invoke any GL functions (it only saves the pointer to your callback).

From the docs:

> `glutMainLoop` enters the GLUT event processing loop.
>   This routine should be called at most once in a GLUT program.
>   Once called, this routine will never return.
>   It will call as necessary any callbacks that have been registered

OpenGL can only render to the GL contexts created in the same thread. Thus the calls to `glClearColor()` and `RenderScene()` will be called in the same thread. Since the call to `glutMainLoop()` is called later in your `main()`, the `glClearColor()` will be called strictly before `glClear()` in `RenderScene()`.